# Propel Regex validation issue

Tags: php, regex, validation, propel

I'm using Propel's validate behavior to validate data on save from within the schema. I have an auto-validator that uses a pre-save hook to validate the data on save.

The schema in question is as follows:

```
<behavior name = "validate">
        <parameter name = "username"
                   value = "{column: username, validator: Regex,
                   options: {pattern: &quot;/^[a-zA-Z0-9_?]{1,20}$/D&quot;}}"/>
        <parameter name = "email" value = "{column: email, validator: Email}"/>
</behavior>
```

The schema for the username column:

```
<column name="username" type="varchar" size="20" required="true" primaryString="true">
```

The validator for the email column is working as expected, however, the validator for usernames is not. It's expected to match usernames that use letters, numbers, underscores, or question marks, of lengths between 1 and 20 characters. In it's current state, an exception is thrown for every save() into this table, including valid usernames.

However, if I change the regex to `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_?]{1,20}/` (removing the $ and D), it allows everything, including invalid usernames.

The relevant Propel documentation can be found [here](http://propelorm.org/documentation/behaviors/validate.html#parameter-tag-value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the "D" modifier. This only changes the behavior when you have a new-line inside the username, but in this case, you are not including \r or \n in the allowed characters group, so it will fail anyway as you expect

```
&quot;/^[a-zA-Z0-9_?]{1,20}$/&quot;
```

You can't remove the dollar sign ($) because in that case, only will be taken in account the first 20 chars of the expression, without failing when you put some more